# Haskell - Automatically using a variable from an imported module

Tags: templates, haskell, dynamic

Let's say I have a module named `Item` that contains:

```
module Item
  ( routes ) where
routes = ["test1","test2","test3"]
```

And in the `Main` module I have:

```
import qualified Item as I
routes = I.routes ++ ["test4", "test5"]
```

I was wondering if it's possible that at compile-time, make `ghc` go through all the imported modules dynamically and if they export a variable named routes, append it to the routes variable that's in the `Main` module. So basically something like this:

```
import qualified Item as I
import qualified User as U --this one exports routes also
import qualified NoRoutes as NR --this one doesn't have any routes
routes = ["test4","test5"]
```

and when compiled, the end result would be `routes = I.routes ++ U.routes ++ ["test4","test5"]`

I'm not sure if Template Haskell does such thing.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Template Haskell would probably be the easiest way to do this.

TH allows you to ask the compiler questions like "does module X export something named Y?" And it allows you to auto-generate the code to append all the routes together.

The alternative is to write a Haskell program that reads your Haskell source code and outputs a text file containing your Main module. That's quite tricky unless all your modules define `routes` in a rather specific way (e.g., always being on line 5 if it exists). TH would probably be much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that with TH ? Because I'm trying to go through the documentation, but I'm not able to find somewhere where it explains modifying module imports. And also I suppose that if I were to use TH, the code would look more complex right ?

Comment: @ft_ It does not allow to modify module import. It, however, allows splice (macro) to inspect compiler state, as I recall, including (qualified) names of visible variables. So you probably can write macro, that, given a variable name, will read names of all visible variables and produce line like `local_routes = concat [Module1.route, Module2.route.... ModuleN.route]`